# как заставить программу правильно работать? [c++]

Tags: c++

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class mysupervector {
    public:
        void setAB(double a, double b) { a = a; b = b; return; }
        long double getLength() { long double ret = (std::sqrt((a*a + b*b))); return(ret); }
    private:
        double a, b;
};



int main() {
    auto acl = new mysupervector;
    int a, b;

    std::cin >> a;
    std::cin >> b;
    acl->setAB(a, b);
    long double len = acl->getLength();
    std::cout << "the vector length is " << len << ".\n";
    char olo;
    std::cin >> olo;
}
```

Вывод всегда такой:   the vector length is 8.87764e+66.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Параметры функции скрывают одноименные члены класса. Поэтому в этом определении функции

```
void setAB(double a, double b) { a = a; b = b; return; }
```

значения параметров `a` и `b` присваиваются самим же параметрам. Для одноименных членов класса вы должны указать квалифицированные имена. Также нет никакого смысла явно в конце функции, объявленной как имеющий тип возврата `void` , указывать предложение `return`.

Определение функции может выглядеть как

```
void setAB( double a, double b ) 
{ 
    this->a = a; 
    this->b = b; 
}
```

или

```
void setAB( double a, double b ) 
{ 
    mysupervector::a = a; 
    mysupervector::b = b; 
}
```

Кроме того в функции `getLength` не имеет смысла указывать тип возвращаемого значения `long double`, так как вы задали аргументы функции `sqrt` , как имеющие тип `double`, а потому возвращаемое значение также будет иметь тип `double`.

Если вы хотите использовать тип `long double`, то вам следует использовать приведение аргументов к типу `long double`..

Эта функция могла бы быть объявлена с квалификатором `const`, так как она не меняет значения объекта класса.

Например,

```
long double getLength() const 
{ 
    return std::sqrt( ( long double )a * a + ( long double )b * b );
}
```

Непонятно, почему вы динамически создаете объект. Тем не менее раз вы его создали таким образом, то следует его удалить в конце программы.

Также не понятно, почему вы используете переменные типа `int` для инициализации членов данных объекта.

К тому же заголовок `<string>` излишний, так как ни одно объявление из этого заголовка не используется.

Программа может выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

class mysupervector 
{
public:
    void setAB( double a, double b ) 
    { 
        this->a = a; 
        this->b = b; 
    }

    long double getLength() const 
    { 
        return std::sqrt( ( long double )a * a + ( long double )b * b );
    }

private:
    double a, b;
};


int main() 
{
    auto acl = new mysupervector;
    double a, b;

    std::cin >> a;
    std::cin >> b;

    acl->setAB( a, b );

    long double len = acl->getLength();

    std::cout << "the vector length is " << len << ".\n";

    delete acl;

    char olo;
    std::cin >> olo;

    return 0;
}
```

Если ввести значения, например, 6 и 8, то вывод на консоль будет:

```
the vector length is 10.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void setAB(double a, double b) { a = a; b = b; return; }
```

Вы присвоили аргументам их же значения...

```
void setAB(double a, double b) { this->a = a; this->b = b; }
```

или

```
void setAB(double aa, double bb) { a = aa; b = bb; }
```

А вообще для этого - установки полей - есть конструктор...